# stage without bar (javafx)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to make a window like eclipse loading by javafx without the bar ,

what I can do !!?

this loading screen

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make a loading splash screen or an undecorated window?

Comment: I don't know, what is the splash screen or  undecorated window  ?

Comment: The loading sceen of Eclipse, as in you post is a splash screen, an undecorated window is a window without window bar, which contains icons to minimize, maximize, close, ...

Comment: ok... it's awesome  i want to splash screen

Comment: Take a look at [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm) and if you have any concrete issues come back here with the details of the question in a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this line. You won't see any title bar in your application.

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Answer (score 1):

hihi,

you could try this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```